# Import azure.core not found issue in running Notebook through MachineLearningStudio

Tags: python-3.x, azure-machine-learning-service

I was trying to run a sample tutorial notebook through the ml studio.

https://notebooks.azure.com/azureml/projects/azureml-getting-started/html/tutorials/img-classification-part1-training.ipynb

But when i uploaded i used kernel python3. But when i ran it failed with the error azureml.core not found.

I am new to Azure Stack and ML. Should i install python 3.6 on my own through conda and have my own kernel, i noticed the current installation of python on studio is 3.4.

Please let me know how to proceed further ? I am blocked on it. I need help on deploying the 3.6 version of python on the notebook server. I am not using the notebook vm. I am just using whatever came with the azure notebook option in the ml studio.

How to alter the sys path to point to my libraries to after installation of the new version of python ?

Need help.

It works fine in my local environment as i have python3.6 installed.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial is for Azure Machine Learning service. The Azure Machine Learning Studio is another product. Running an AzureML service sample notebook using AzuerML Studio will not give you the required Azureml.core library. Please go to portal.azure.com and create an Azure Machine Learning service workspace first. Then running the sample in your workspace's notebook VM.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am new to this Azure space.